# Map JSON to POJO Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I'm trying to get map a JSON to a POJO using jackson and I keep getting the following error:

```
> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (String)\"{\"checkstyle\
```

The JSON Im trying to parse is the following:

```
{
  "checkstyle": {
    "file": [
      {
        "name": "src\\main\\java\\com\\report\\uploader\\controller\\RandomController.java",
        "error": [
          {
            "severity": "error",
            "line": 0,
            "source": "com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocPackageCheck",
            "message": "Missing package-info.java file."
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "version": 6.18
  }
}
```

For this I create the following classes:

```
public class Checkstyle {

    @JsonProperty("checkstyle")
    private Linter linterName;
}

public class Linter {

    @JsonProperty("file")
    private List<File> files;

    @JsonProperty("version")
    private String version;
}

public class File {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("error")
    private List<Error> errores;

}

public class Error {

    @JsonProperty("severity")
    private String severity;

    @JsonProperty("line")
    private int line;

    @JsonProperty("source")
    private String source;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;
}
```

But when I run the code I get the error mentioned above. The way I get this JSON is by converting an XML file to a JSONObject using the `org.json` dependency and then the JSONobject I convert it to a String.

Then I convert then I try to convert the String into my POJO the following way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Checkstyle checkstyle = mapper.readValue(object.toString(), Checkstyle.class);
```

If anyone could point me out what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line causing error in your program `mapper.readValue(object.toString(), Checkstyle.class)`. You have already read the json into an anonymous `object`, and then using its `toString()` representation in ObjectMapper to map to `Checkstyle` class, which will never work. As you already have lost the json string into java default toString representation of object: `someObjectClassname@hashcodenumber`.

Below are the some of the commonly used signature of `readValue` method to do correrct de-serialization:

> readValue(InputStream in, Class c)
>   readValue(Reader rd, Class c)
>   readValue(String json, Class c)